# Negative Lookbehind expression for not ending with exp : '\w+(?<!exp)\b' or '\w+\b(?<!exp)'

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

For expression `(?<!foo)`,Negative Lookbehind ,asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is not foo.
Now to match string not ending with characters  `abc`.
The formal expression is `\w+(?<!abc)\b` or `\b\w+(?<!abc)\b`.

```
echo "xxabc jkl" | grep -oP  '\w+(?<!abc)\b'
jkl
```

Let's try another form:  `\w+\b(?<!abc)`.

```
echo "xxabc jkl" | grep -oP  '\w+\b(?<!abc)'
jkl
```

It get correct answer too.
In my opinion, `\w+\b(?<!abc)` is not a Negative Lookbehind,nothing behind `(?<!abc)`,it can't called Negative Lookbehind.
1.Is expression `\w+\b(?<!abc)` a Negative Lookbehind?
2.Why `\w+\b(?<!abc)` has the same effct as `\w+(?<!abc)\b`?

Comment: Keep in mind that `\b` is a zero-width match - it doesn't matter whether it comes before or after, the lookbehind will be checked for a match at exactly the same point in the string.

Answer (score 1):

1)It is a negative lookback window. Negative lookback is used if you want to match something not proceeded by something else.
`?<!abc` is a **negative** look back window. So it will only be true if the proceeding tokens are **not** "abc" which is true with the string provided: `"xxabc jkl"` technically, a space is proceeding `"jkl"` Therefore it matches.

2) `\b` looks for a word boundary. Word boundaries apply for spaces and end of strings which are present in both of your regular expressions. If you really want to see a difference, try taking the space out of the input. So
 use `"xxabcjkl"`