# How to explain the same structure expression `(?=\w{6,10})\d+ and (?=abc)ad`?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

```
debian@wifi:~$ echo "348dfgeccvdf" | grep -oP "\d+(?=\w{6,10})"
348
debian@wifi:~$ echo "348dfgeccvdf" | grep -oP "(?=\w{6,10})\d+"
348
```

For `\d+(?=\w{6,10})` ,it is the standard  positive look ahead expression.
As Wiktor Stribiżew say in the post
[position and  negative lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45646773/negative-lookbehind-expression-for-not-ending-with-exp-wexp-b-or-w)
The negative lookbehind syntax starts with `(?<! and ends with the unescaped )`. Whether it appears at the start, middle or end of the pattern, it does not stop from being a negative lookbehind.
Maybe it's no realtionship between position and whole lookahead(lookbehind) expression.

To infer for positive look ahead according to the same logic ,such as  Wiktor Stribiżew say for negative lookbehind:

```
"\d+(?=\w{6,10})" == "(?=\w{6,10})\d+"
```

Both of them are positive look ahead.

Now here is another example:

```
echo  "adabc  adabb" |grep -oP  "ad(?=abc)"
ad
echo  "adabc  adabb" |grep -oP  "(?=abc)ad"
```

Why  `"ad(?=abc)"` is not equal to `"(?=abc)ad"` ?
How to explain the same structure expression  `(?=\w{6,10})\d+ and (?=abc)ad`  ?

Comment: Lookarounds are [zero-length assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) they are "fired" at a certain position between characters/start/end. At this position they "look" forward or behind for the defined condition.

Comment: In Wiktors sample, he is changing the position of a word boundary (`\b`) and a negative lookbehind - this is possible due to the fact that both are zero-width-assertions. In your sample, you exchange a lookahead and a matching pattern - which leads to a fundamental different overall pattern.

Comment: And you seem to have misread his _Whether it appears at the start, middle or end of the pattern_. This does not say, that the matching progress is the same independent of the position of the lookaround - just that lookaround pattern remains a lookaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why  "ad(?=abc)" is not equal to "(?=abc)ad" ?

`ad(?=abc)` explains `ad` followed by `abc` whereas `(?=abc)ad` will not match with any input string. Cause expecting 'followed by abc' `(?=abc)` but defining `ad` after positive lookahead !  . Pattern should be like this `(?=abc)\w+` to match with this input string `abcad`

> How to explain the same structure expression  (?=\w{6,10})\d+ and (?=abc)ad ?

`(?=\w{6,10})\d+` this pattern also will not match  as this `(?=abc)ad` for any input string. Pattern supposed to be like this :

`(?=\w{6,10})\w+` and `(?=abc)\w+`.

Answer (score 1):

> Wiktor Stribiżew say for negative lookbehind:
>
> ```
> "\d+(?=\w{6,10})" == "(?=\w{6,10})\d+"
> ```

That's not what he said. His example was specifically with a *word boundary*, which is a zero-length assertion as well. Only

```
…(?lookaround)\b… == …\b(?lookaround)…
```

can hold.

> Why `"ad(?=abc)"` is not equal to `"(?=abc)ad"`?

Because one asserts the sequence `abc` after the match `ad` while the other tries to assert it at the begin (which will always fail).